# Apply operation to column

Tags: python, pandas

I import a dataframe which has a column 'Goals' that accumulates the previous results, like so:

```
print (df[df['name']=='Player Name']['Goals'])

152     1.0
828     2.0
1591    3.0
```

---

I know for a fact that the player scored only one goal per game, so the column should be like:

```
152     1.0
828     1.0
1591    1.0
```

---

By the way the same logic applies to all other scout columns:

```
...
FF                 322 non-null float64
FS                 568 non-null float64
Goals              80 non-null float64
A                  63 non-null float64
PI                 834 non-null float64
SG                 140 non-null float64
DD                 46 non-null float64
DS                 611 non-null float64
FC                 602 non-null float64
GC                 3 non-null float64
GS                 45 non-null float64
FD                 231 non-null float64
CA                 190 non-null float64
FT                 34 non-null float64
I                  112 non-null float64
PP                 4 non-null float64
CV                 9 non-null float64
...
```

---

**QUESTION**

What is the best way to correct this logic and apply this subtraction to the subset of columns above?

---

Edit:

```
df['G'] = df['G'].diff()
```

returns

```
Name: G, dtype: float64
152    NaN
828    NaN
1562   NaN
```

Comment: Take a look at the [diff function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html). But you will need a groupby before diff to avoid subtracting one player's goal from another. Post your full dataframe for a better answer

Comment: assign them as 1 ?

Comment: @CodeDifferent please refer to my edit

Answer (score 0):

Writing this in the blind as you have not shown the full DataFrame:

```
for col in ['Goals', 'FF', 'FS', ...]:
    tmp = df.groupby('name')[col].diff().fillna(1)
    df[col] = tmp
```